# Filtering using KendoGrid with MVC not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

I am using KendoUI and I wanted to do some research on the how it does the filtering. I came across a code snippet below:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/filter-row

And I wrote a code which looks like following:

```
<div id="clientsDb">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Prometheus.Core.Domain.Employee>()
              .Name("employeeGrid")
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Width(140).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")));
                  columns.Bound(c => c.FirstName).Width(190).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")));
                  columns.Bound(c => c.LastName);
              })
              .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "height: 380px;"})
              .Scrollable()
              .Groupable()
              .Sortable()
              .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                  .Refresh(true)
                  .PageSizes(true)
                  .ButtonCount(5))
              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                  .Ajax()
                  .Read(read => read.Action("ReadEmployee", "EmployeeGrid"))))
```

I am not seeing any errors but I am not seeing any search filter enabled any where in the Grid.

However, the following code is working fine for me which is adding filter at the grid level rather than adding it at the column level:

```
<div id="clientsDb">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Prometheus.Core.Domain.Employee>()
              .Name("employeeGrid")
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Width(140).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")));
                  columns.Bound(c => c.FirstName).Width(500).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")));
                  columns.Bound(c => c.LastName);
              })
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 380px;" })
              .Scrollable()
              .Groupable()
              .Sortable()
              .Selectable()
              .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                  .Refresh(true)
                  .PageSizes(true)
                  .ButtonCount(5))
                  .Filterable(filterable => filterable
                .Extra(true)
                .Operators(operators => operators
                    .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                        .Contains("Contains")
                        .IsEqualTo("Exactly matches")
                        .StartsWith("Starts with")
                        .DoesNotContain("Does not contain")
                        .EndsWith("Ends with")
                        .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
                    ))).DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                  .Ajax()
                  .Read(read => read.Action("ReadEmployee", "EmployeeGrid"))))
        </div>
```

I am not sure what is a big difference here since both are using pretty much same filterable attribute. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to apply Filterable() to in the first code.

Comment: Actually I did as you can see in the sample :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really late reply, but you need to add `.Filterable(filter => filter.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))` at the grid level in your first example. It's worth noting that in order to use the `.Cell(etc...)` style in your column it NEEDS to be in Row filter mode as the menu mode doesn't support per column options.

It would be a good question as to why that's the case, but there it is.